# Proper way to perform privileged tasks from wsgi app

Tags: python, django, root, wsgi, iptables

I need to write a small wsgi app for manipulating iptables. I use nginx + uwsgi on Debian with [python-iptables](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-iptables/) package.

uwsgi runs as www-data user by default, so if I try to access iptables from my app I got `iptc.ip4tc.IPTCError: can't initialize filter: Permission denied (you must be root)`.

Is there any workaround to this problem except running the whole wsgi app as root? And what should I do if I want to integrate my app with Django (I definitely don't want run all Django stuff as root)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to exctract all the functionality which needs superuser privileges into separate script (for example `script.py`) owned by root (`chown root script.py`), allow exectution of it (`chmod u+x script.py`), then set [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) to allow execution rights on that file with root permissions to other users (`chmod u+s script.py`).

Then you should be able to call that script from your wsgi application using subprocess and www-data privileges.